# How many events can we add to iCal from iphone App?

Tags: iphone, events, icalendar

I have one critical problem in my iphone app. From this iphone app user can add their events to iPhone iCal app. Now, the problem is the events i can not add many more events (Continuously 170 events at a time by For loop)to ical. If i do this only 150 events can add to ical and i got the EventID(Unique Event identifier), after balance events can't add in iCAl and the EventID return 'Null'. Can anyone please help to solve this problem? There is any limitation to add events to iCal app from iphone app? Thanks in advance. Thanks for spending your valuable time with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a hard limit on the amount we can add. I can say that I have added 500+ without problems. I have noticed that sometimes the Calendar App on the phone freezes and stops responding after I have interacted with it, but I think that is data related. I have also noticed that the iPhone Calendar app behaves a bit different deepening on the calendar you are adding events to. For example, whether it is a google calendar or the "On my iPhone" calendar. It sounds like you are having a different problem though.

I would suggest looking at the (NSError **)error object after saving the events to see what the exact error is, and then asking a new question related to the error you are receiving.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello friend. I followed your guide lines. There i got an error message while adding Multiple events to iCal. The Error Message is "Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "The event has no calendar set." UserInfo=0xfee4d90 {NSLocalizedDescription=The event has no calendar set.}" How to solve this? Can you please guide me to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Apple provides very good documentation on working with the iPhone Calendar. I would read the entire Event Kit Programming guide, especially the "Creating and Editing Events Programmatically" section. If you still have problems, I would ask a new question. Make sure you are using: eventWithEventStore to create your EKEvent. [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I also read the EKEvent documentation from Apple. Am using eventWithEventStore in my code. I have posted another one question regarding this in StackOverFlow. This is that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977151/add-events-to-ical-from-iphone-app-the-event-has-no-calendar-set-error. Can you please solve my problem? I spend two full days for finding the solution for this problem, But still i cant solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I'll look at the question, and give some suggestions. Not sure if it will solve it or not, I hope you can figure it out.